# Failed to start Spring Boot app on Heroku after building succesfully

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I get code from my GitHub repo and build it with the Heroku Gradle build pack. The logs show it was built successfully and app was started. I visit the site and I get no response -- App fails to bootrun after build

I fail to see in the logs the same output as when a spring boot app bootruns.

I created a text file `Procfile` and in it is

```
web java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a colon after the process type (`web`) in your `Procfile`:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

'$JAVA_OPTS' was missing

```
web java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar /build/libs/*.jar
```